# Dealing with Japanese characters

Tags: c++

So I was reading 'Accelerated C++' and there I read about `wchar_t`, I Googled a Japanese character and threw in the following statement in my program:

`wchar_t japs = 'の';`

It gave me this error:

```
input.cpp:20:20: warning: multi-character character constant [-Wmultichar]
     wchar_t japs = 'の';
```

I don't know Japanese but I am clueless about what is happening here. Googled a bit, some solutions were talking about, it being a Linux issue, some solutions were talking about UTF-8 encoding.

Can someone really tell, what is actually happening? My environment in `Ubuntu`?

Comment: Literals enclosed in plain single-quotes are *narrow* character literals. You might possibly want a *wide* character literals using the `L` prefix. As in `L'の'`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude It worked. One more question, if I try to print it using `std::cout << japs`, it produces `12398`. How come?

Comment: read this https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/ and this http://kunststube.net/encoding/ plus C++ standard support for Unicode is utterly abysmal

Comment: I had good luck with `std::cout << "\u306E" << std::endl;`, but that is platform dependent.  C++ standard support for Unicode is embarrassingly underwhelming.

Comment: OP, it's vital you understand the principle here: C++ chars are **ASCII characters**, which are one or two bytes long respectively, and use a particular encoding that's been around for a long time. `wchar` expands on this a bit, but it's still only two (?) bytes long. By contract, **Unicode** characters span anywhere from 1-4 characters. Japanese characters, in particular, are 3 bytes long IIRC. C++ handles them by storing the Unicode character (or any number of them) as a *string* of `char`s, and then interpreting the string as UTF-8 (or whatever other Unicode) encoding.

Comment: Take some time and read the article *[The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets, No Excuses](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/)* by Joel Spolsky.

Answer (score 4):

Your Editor supports Utf8. If you enter this character 'の' it will be encoded as a sequence of characters [ 0xe3, 0x81, 0xae ].
wchar_t is a typedef for a integer value. you should use the UTF8 encoding and store the characters in strings. e.g. char japs[] = "の";
If your terminal supports utf-8 (it normaly does) you can use japanese characters in c-strings, as you would use latin characters. bit keep in mind that one japanese character occupies three or more bytes in a c-string. 
This type of string is called a multi-byte-string. if you like trouble you can convert a string with utf8 encoded characters to an array of wchar_t type. usualy each character will take 32bit. see "man mbstowcs".

Comment: `char japs[] = "の"` worked! I was able to print `の` on the console.